# jQuery value passing as a id in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It is possible to pass a jQuery variable as a Id in Html. For example

```
 $(document).on('click', '.addvideo', function () {
     var dynamicID = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Here I am getting the currently clicked id value "dynamicID". I want pass this value to another variable, like below

```
$('#'+dynamicID).change(function(){
    alert('hi');
    });
```

I tried like above. But i am getting error "**ReferenceError: dynamicID is not defined**". How to resolve this problem ?

Comment: it's in a completely different scope, which is why you're running into problems. The question I have is: why would you want to reselect an element you already have? You could just store the reference to the DOM node and not have to reselect at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write change event inside addvideo click event, then only it will bind:

```
$(document).on('click', '.addvideo', function () {
     var dynamicID = $(this).attr('id');
     $('#'+dynamicID).change(function(){
        alert('hi');
     });
});
```

Comment: Assuming ids are unique wont this simply be `$(this).change(...)` w/o extracting id and selecting the same element by id?

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by you trying to access the variable `dynamicID` from somewhere it is not available.

Variables in JS are only accessible within the function that defines them, in other words the part where you write `var something = 'value'`.

so in your example, the variable `dynamicID` is available anywhere within this function, but not outside of it.

```
$(document).on('click', '.addvideo', function () {
     var dynamicID = $(this).attr('id');
});
console.log(dynamicID) //ReferenceError: dynamicID is not defined
```

When you try to access `dynamicID` outside the function you will get an error, because it basically doesn't exist there.

So you could move the function that is using the `dynamicID` inside the function that defines it:

```
$(document).on('click', '.addvideo', function () {
     var dynamicID = $(this).attr('id');
     $('#'+dynamicID).change(function(){
        alert('hi');
     });
});
```

Or to access the variable somewhere else you can define it outside the function, assign it a value in the function, and then access it from somewhere else.

```
var dynamicID;
$(document).on('click', '.addvideo', function () {
     dynamicID = $(this).attr('id');
});

console.log(dynamicID) //this will log the ID value provided the element has been clicked
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting that error, is that you are in a different scope, meaning that dynamicID won't be defined. Try adding it into the same scope like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.addvideo', function () {

    var dynamicID = $(this).attr('id');

    $('#'+dynamicID).change(function(){
        alert('hi');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know how you intend to fetch the dynamic Id but imagine you're trying to get it from a textbox. Here's how I would do it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dynamicID = '#' + $('#yada').val();

  $(dynamicID).on('input', function(e) {
    alert('hi');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="yada" value="yada">
```